# How to filter a list from a Django query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have following scenario. I have 3 models - School, User, SchoolTeacher. A teacher can be part of many schools. Now, when a user searches we display list of schools based on some criteria. We also want to display for each school, whether user is a teacher in that school. Now, I want to get the result in one query, so I have done this

```
users_list = list(SchoolTeacher.objects.filter(school__in = result_list, user=self.user).values('school_id'))

users_teacher_ids = []

for item in users_list :
        users_teacher_ids .append(item['school_id'])
```

And, then I attach to each School object,

```
schoolobj.is_user_teacher = schoolobj.id in users_teacher_ids
```

Can I do something better than this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your models look like this:

```
class School(models.Model):
   # -- your fields

class SchoolTeacher(models.Model):
   schools = models.ManyToManyField(School)
   # -- other fields
```

You can then do this:

```
my_school = School.objects.get(pk=1)
my_school.schoolteacher_set.all() # all teachers in a particular school
```

See [many to many reverse relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#m2m-reverse-relationships) in the documentation for more info.